# Insert Into Table1 Select x, y, z From Table2 Where x = 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In mssql is it possible to run this query:

```
Insert Into Table1 Select x, y, z From Table2 Where x = 1
```

when Table1 has an id column that is identity & auto-incrementing

I am getting the following error:

Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: How many fields does `Table1` have?

Comment: What are your desired results?  Do you want to insert a new record in `Table` with id = 1?  If so, you need to do as the error specifies.  If you don't want to copy the id value, but rather just want to use the increment, specify the column names in the insert and don't insert the id...

Comment: Table1 has fields x, y, z and id

I am trying to append from table2 into table1...schemas are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its should be as simple as

```
Insert Into Table1 (x, y, z)  --<-- Explicitly mention the column names
Select x, y, z 
From Table2 
Where x = 1
```

You do not need to mention ID column anywhere, it auto-generates the Identity value for your and insert in that column.

Comment: I just found it too!  Thanks! This was the problem.  I was not including the target columns for table1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` on to insert identities, then turn it off when you are done.  This is what the syntax will look like.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON;

Insert Into Table1 (column1A, column1B, column1C)
    Select Column2A, Column2B, Column2C
       From Table 2
          Where Column2A = 1;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF;
```

Comment: It is not possible to have the receiving table assign the id values?

Comment: I should note that the identity column (id) is not x, y, or z.

Comment: this answer has the answer too, I was thinking about identity_insert and missed it.  Thanks!

Comment: my answer assumes you want to persist the IDs from `Table2`.  If you want `Table1` to assign new IDs, don't specify the ID column, as m.Ali suggested.